# Post too large Exeception in Sun one application server

Tags: sun-one

Hi I am getting following exeception after posting the lasrge amount of Data.

```
[#|2010-03-01T23:36:49.764-0600|WARNING|sun-appserver-ee8.1_02|javax.enterprise.system.stream.err|_ThreadID=31;|java.lang.IllegalStateException: Post too large
        at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteRequest.parseRequestParameters(CoyoteRequest.java:2607)
        at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteRequest.getParameter(CoyoteRequest.java:1139)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to set maxPostSize on your http connector, somehow.

I'm not sure that's possible on your version of the application server:

Here's a link to a 8.2 docs that *don't* mention maxPostSize as an http-listener property:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4723/abhck/index.html

And newer glassfish docs which do:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4338/abhck/index.html

Tomcat's http connector supports the same property, has a 2M default.